# How true is Delilah's story?

Tags: dishonored

In *Dishonored 2*, Delilah Copperspoon tells the story of her upbringing in Dunwall Tower as the illegitimate child of Emperor Kaldwin and a servant. As the firstborn, she says that her father repeatedly told her that she would be princess someday, while at the same time hiding her from the public.

More importantly, she claims that Jessamine lied and said Delilah broke some dishes while they were playing. As a result, she was sent away with her mother to debtors prison, and they were never contacted by the royal family again.
There's never anything really contradicting the tale, although the heart of Jessamine is as vague as always and never admits anything. **Is all of this true, or just a half-truth warped by Delilah's hatred? Or is it left to the player to decide?**

Perhaps some of this is answered in *The Brigmore Witches*, which I've never played. Feel free to spoil away if necessary.

In my last playthrough as Emily, I played her as merciless and vengeful as possible. The few allies she had were not very forthcoming with information, so it's possible that had I played more peacefully, I would have gotten more of the story.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The game wiki provides no evidence not to believe her story but the truth of her version of history is purposely left ambiguous. Her backstory does make for a more sympathetic antagonist. You can understand her need for some sort of vengeance as opposed to the stereotypical mustache-twirling variety of villain.

(http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Delilah_Copperspoon)

- " It is left ambiguous whether her remembrances of the past reflect reality or whether the truth has been warped by her lies and/or insanity."

*note: During my own playthrough, I had the impression of someone telling the truth but had become so obsessed with what was done to her (and how her Mom died) that she lost all sight of what was right or wrong. Vengeance became the only thing worth pursuing. Everything, every action served that end. Even remaking reality. My own opinion of course.